# $f : G \to H$ grp hom ,$F : \Bbb Z[G] \to \Bbb Z[H]$: induced homomorphism of group rings. Show that $I_G = F^{-1}(I_H )$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, category-theory, homological-algebra

**Let $f : G \to H$ be a homomorphism of groups, and let $F : \Bbb Z[G] \to \Bbb Z[H]$ be the
induced homomorphism of group rings.
Show that $I_G = F^{-1}(I_H )$.**

I tried this:

I have by definition that $I_G = ker(a_G) \subseteq \Bbb Z[G]$ is the so called augmentation ideal which is the ideal generated by all the elements of the form $g-e$, with $g \in G$ and $a_G:\Bbb Z[G] \to \Bbb Z$ the augmentation map. $\Bbb Z[G]$ is the group ring of $G$.Similarly for H I can define the same objects.

I think I have to show the double inclusion , so to show for instance that  $F^{-1}(I_H )\subseteq I_G $, I take $x \in F^{-1}(I_H )=\{x \in \Bbb Z[G]: F(x)\in I_H\}$.

I also know that :

- the elements of $Z[G]$ are of the form $\sum_{g \in G}m_g\cdot g$ with all but finitely many non-zero terms
- the map

$F: \sum_{g \in G}m_g\cdot g \mapsto  \sum_{h \in H}n_h\cdot h$  with $n_h= \sum_{g \in f^{-1}(h)}m_g$

- the map

$a_G: \sum_{g \in G}m_g\cdot g \mapsto \sum_{g \in G}m_g  $

So let $x=\sum_{g \in G}m_g\cdot g$. The condition $F(x)\in I_H=ker(a_H)$ translates into

$0=a_H(F(x))=a_H(F(\sum_{g \in G}m_g\cdot g))=a_H(\sum_{h \in H}n_h\cdot h)=\sum_{h \in H}n_h$ with $n_h= \sum_{g \in f^{-1}(h)}m_g$

But I don't see how to get to $x \in I_G = $ ker $ a_G$ which means $a_G(x)=0$

**How should I do that provided this is the right track? If not how should I proceed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a right track. You can use that, as $h$ varies over all elements in $H$, the sets $f^{-1}(h)$ form a partition of the set $G$. That means that $\sum_{h\in H}\sum_{g\in f^{-1}(h)} m_g = \sum_{g\in G} m_g = a_G(x).$

Indeed, it holds that $a_H\circ F = a_G$, and the equality $I_G=F^{-1}(I_H)$ follows immediately from this. Namely, if you know that $a_H\circ F= a_G$, then you have $a_G(x)=0$ iff $F(x)$ satisfies $a_H(F(x))=0$. In other words, $x\in I_G$ iff $x\in F^{-1}(I_H)$.

To show the equality $a_H\circ F= a_G$, I think it is easier to think about $F\colon\mathbb{Z}[G]\to\mathbb{Z}[H]$ as the unique $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map that sends $g$ to $f(g)$. Therefore, $a_H\circ F(g)= a_G(g)$ for any $g\in G$, so since the elements of $G$ form a generating set for $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ and both sides of our desired equality are $\mathbb{Z}$-linear, this just shows that this equality holds.

Comment: How does $I_G=F^{-1}(I_H)$ follow immediately from the other one?

Comment: If you know that $a_H\circ F= a_G$, then you have $a_G(x)=0$ iff $F(x)$ satisfies $a_H(F(x))=0$. In other words, $x\in I_G$ iff $x\in F^{-1}(I_H)$. I also edited this into the answer for convenience.

Comment: To complete my method, how would I go about proving the opposite inclusion?

Comment: and could you elaborate on why $\Bbb Z-$linearity and the fact that G is a generating set of $\Bbb Z[G]$ imply that $a_H\circ F = a_G$ ?

Comment: For your first question: you would reverse your chain of equalities that you used for the other inclusion: you would start with $x$ such that $a_G(x)=0$, and the chain of equalities that you have in your question, together with the final step that I wrote in the first paragraph of my answer, can be reversed to show that $a_H(F(x))=a_G(x)=0$. In principle, you're doing the same thing as what I propose in the second paragraph of my answer, just more explicit and with a little bit more work.

Comment: @some_math_guy For your second question: it's similar to how two linear maps are equal if they are equal on the elements of some basis. A general element of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of elements of $G$, but for simplicity let's take $x=ag_1+bg_2\in \mathbb{Z}[G]$. Then $F(x)=aF(g_1)+bF(g_2)$, and $a_H\circ F(x)=a\cdot a_H F(g_1) + b\cdot a_H F (g_2)=a\cdot a_G(g_1)+ b \cdot a_G(g_2)=a_G(x)$, just from knowing that all maps are $\mathbb{Z}$-linear and that the equality holds on $G$. For a general $x$, the argument is similar.

Comment: But also note that in your approach, you also essentially showed that $a_H\circ F= a_G$, so you can also use that argument if you;re more comfortable with that. However, I think it's good to know other method I use, since it makes it easier.

Comment: Yeah, I like your method, just wanted to make sure to understand them both.